# Why games don't show layout bounds?

Tags: android

When I enabled show layout bounds option in my android mobile, it shows layouts for every app but never seen a game which shows layouts. Why we can't see layouts for games?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, they are not using layouts. OpenGL games, for example, frequently have a single `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` for their entire content.